Как реализовать выбор аватарки в Django
Я недавно решил изучить django и сделать магазин игр. Столкнулся с тем, что не могу реализовать выбор пользователем аватарки при регистрации. html регистрации написал, а логику сделать не понимаю как, в интернете видел, что для этого расширяют стандартную модель пользователя с помощью AbstractUser но я так ничего и не понял. Ниже прикреплю ссылку на гитхаб. подберите или напишите пожалуйста какой-нибудь пример кода.
https://github.com/Maxitovitch/Game_shop.git

Я бы предложил вам реализовать отдельное поле, которое отвечает за выбор картинки для аватара в файловой системе пользователя. Выбранную картинку можно сохранить в файловой системе сервера в папке, соответствующей учётной записи (или email-у, если имена пользователей могут совпадать) пользователя. При необходимости показать аватар пользователя сервер достанет его в файловой системе.

Насколько я вас понял, мне по-сути вообще не нужно пока связывать пользователя с аватаркой. Я могу в моделях создать отдельный класс который будет принимать аватарку, а затем связывать её например с именем пользователя. А чтобы отобразить её когда нужно мы просто проверяем какая аватарка совпадает с именем пользователя и всё?

Да, ведь основными атрибутами пользователя выступают имя пользователя и пароль. Остальное (с точки зрения Django) - дополнение от разработчика. Поля для аватара и ввода основных атрибутов пользователя можно и совместить, при этом прописав действия над ними в одной функции, но это не совсем рационально.
